# How to get extra achievements at the talos principle?

Tags: achievements, the-talos-principle

I finished the game and reached all 3 endings, but there are still quite a lot achievements, which I haven't got (in order of "i have no idea how to get it"):

1. LOL (Laugh at the pointlessness of existence). What the hell is it?)) Can I laugh at this game?
2. Split Personality (Communicate with your double). I touched my record and the Shepard too.
3. Hedging My Bets (Do as you're told (for now)). I did how I was told quite a few times, following Elohim's order to collect sigils, to go on the light, to turn back from the stairs - all these doesn't help.
4. Know Your Limits (Accept Elohim's wisdom). Again, I turned back and went to the lighting door, accepting what Elohim told me, but didn't got this achievement.
5. Press The Serpent (Expose the flaws in the code). I know that I can reach the code by pressing F1, and I even changed a value of one variable, this didn't help me.

How to get them?
Please use spoiler tags.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read Elisav the Evil's [Total Achievement Guide](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=355470944) to know how to get the various achievements.

Regarding the ones you mentioned (text taken semi-verbatim from the guide):

- **LOL:** Type LOL using Sigils (Tetrominos) in a gate-puzzle. (Two L shaped pieces and a square piece.)
- **Split Personality:** While using the Recroding mechanic, paint a QR message on a wall. After ending the recording, read the QR message that you recorded moments ago. The hardest part should be actually finding the paint can.
- **Hedging My Bets:** Do not ascend the tower until you have collected all 49 of the Red Sigils (Tetrominos). Basically, don't solve any Red Puzzle Gate until you have all of the Red Sigils (Tetrominos).
- **Know Your Limits:** When Elohim tells you something along the lines of leave this one for another time, you don't have to solve everything now, follow his advice and go solve another puzzle instead. This can be easily missed as Elohim will only tell you that so many times in one playthrough.
- **Press The Serpent:** Read the *Deal With The Deceiver, Press the serpent, Silence the Serpent - Common Elements* and *Press The Serpent - continued* sections of the guide, it's too long to copy them here; basically you need to choose certain dialogue option when speaking with Milton.

Comment: B-4 is perfect for getting Split Personality because the paint can is right next to the entrance to a recording puzzle (the first puzzle on your left on entering B-4).

Answer (score 0):

I've found one.

**4. Know Your Limits (Accept Elohim's wisdom).** You get this achievement when you can't solve a puzzle for a long time and Elohim talks to you that you can postpone it for another day and you go out from the puzzle area after that.